# Openstack - Nova client - Retrieve servers for particular tenant

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova

I need to get the list of servers which is available for particular tenant.

That is consider tenant_id of tenant is as follows:

```
ee13ef5e10644f3782179bbfac1cdab5
```

Now I need to get the server which is available only for particular tenant.

I have tried the code as follows:

I am unable to get the result.

It just showing me an empty list when I tried the same.

```
from novaclient import client
import json


kwargs = {
    "tenant_name":'admin',
    "auth_url":'http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0',
    "username":'admin',
    "password":'password',
}

# Establish the connection Keystone
keystone = client.Client('2', 'admin', 'sop52maw', 'admin', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0')

server_list = keystone.servers.list(search_opts={'tenant_id':'ee13ef5e10644f3782179bbfac1cdab5'})
print server_list
```

Someone have a look and guide me to sort this one out.

Answer (score 3):

By default nova only returns the instances associated with the tenant that makes the call, and in this case it is the `admin` tenant. To inform nova to return the instances from all tenants then you can add that to the `search_opts`:

```
nova = client.Client('2', 'admin', 'sop52maw', 'admin', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0')
search_opts = {'tenant_id':'ee13ef5e10644f3782179bbfac1cdab5', 'all_tenants': 1}
server_list = nova.servers.list(search_opts=search_opts)
```

Note: not sure why you called the nova client `keystone` but that confused the hell out of me. Keystone is the identity service and you are obviously talking to the compute service (Nova).